# Update a MKPolyline when current location of user chage

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I draw with MKPolyline a line between an existed location and the current location of user.
When view appears everything is fine and the line is correctly, but when the current location of user change i want that the line between the two locations update too.
This is my code

```
-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
self.currentLatitude = userLocation.coordinate.latitude;
self.currentLongitude = userLocation.coordinate.longitude;

[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"self.currentLatitude" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];
[self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"self.currentLongitude" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew context:nil];  
}


-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
   // Remove the old overlay
[self.mapView removeOverlay:self.routeLine];

if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"self.currentLatitude"])
{
   self.newCurrentLatitude = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] floatValue];
}

if ([keyPath isEqualToString:@"self.currentLongitude"])
{
        self.newCurrentLongitude = [[change valueForKey:@"new"] floatValue];
}

// Draw line between user location and location that had choosen in table
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinateArray[2];
coordinateArray[0] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.newCurrentLatitude, self.newCurrentLongitude);
coordinateArray[1] = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(self.latitudeOfPlaceFromTable, self.longitudeOfPlaceFromTable);

self.routeLine = [MKPolyline polylineWithCoordinates:coordinateArray count:2];
[self.mapView setVisibleMapRect:[self.routeLine boundingMapRect]];
[self.mapView addOverlay:self.routeLine];
}
```

Can someone helps me ? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

MKPolyline is immutable, so you will need to remove overlay with removeOverlay method and add a new one with a new polyline as you did before.

Comment: i removed the old overlay as in updated code, but is not working. do you think i should made an NSMutableArray "coordinateArray" with CLLocationCoordinate2D  ?

Comment: Does method called second time after coordinates update? This whole observing logic is suspicious in general. I would ged rid of it by moving everything into update overlay method, and calling it directly from the place where coordinates updating. Ina current setup there is an overhead because of double call on change of each properties etc.

Comment: As for nsmutablearray I do not think it is needed here

Comment: After first if, self.newCurrentLatitude is updated, but it jumps over second if (self.currentLongitude) and goes directly to the end. That gives me something like that "self.currentLatitude 45.565674, self.currentLongitude 0.000000". I already added the contexts and is the same results. :((

Comment: As I mentioned, I would recommend to remove observing at all, as it adds unnecessary complexity. If there is an issue with Map updates, I would prefer to solve it but not Map updates + Observing :) Here is a suggested code update to simplify everything — https://gist.github.com/nikita-leonov/d83023abd870f3b93ff8

Comment: Do your indeed receive new coordinates in compare with initial?